# Creating a shortcut to connect to a Bluetooth PAN in Win8

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, bluetooth, shortcuts

I have paired my cell phone with my computer via bluetooth. Whenever I want to use its network connection (over a Bluetooth PAN), I need to click on the Bluetooth Icon, select "Join a Personal Area Network", click on the device (Samsung Galaxy S III), select "Connect using" and finally select "Access point".

If I create a shortcut to the device itself, it offers me "File Transfer", "Music and Audio" (Connect) and "Remote Keyboard and Mouse" (Connect) but not the PAN/network connection.

That's pretty annoying.

Is there any way to get a shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Bluetooth Icon, select "Join a Personal Area Network", right-click on the device (in your case Samsung Galaxy S III), select "Create shortcut", this will create a shortcut on the desktop that you can right-click and select "Connect to -> Access point"